# Is there a way to loop through the front matter of a jekyll collection?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter, prose

I have a Jekyll collection which is not being output, but elements of which are being displayed on a single page, like this:

```
{% for element in site.collection %}
  {{ element.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
{% for element in site.collection %}
  {{ element.content }}
  {% for front_matter in element %}
    <!-- do stuff -->
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is possible with YAML hashes in YAML _data files, but doesn't work here because, it seems `{{ element }}` on its own is identical to `{{ element.content }}`. There doesn't seem to be any variable designated for this either like, `{{ element.front_matter }}`. Is it possible to loop through the front matter of an element in a jekyll collection?

I know that the ideal way to do this would be to include all the front_matter I want to loop through in a variable, like:

```
---
front_matter:
  foo: bar
  bar: foo
---
```

But, as I'm trying to configure these pairings (`foo` and `bar`) to be easily updatable through prose.io, they can't be nested under other values. If there is a 
way around this with prose though, I would accept that answer.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to loop through the variables of an element in a Jekyll collection:

```
{% for items in site.my_collection %}
  {% for item in items %}
    {{ item }}: {{ items[item] }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it is important to remember that there is other metadata that is also available and will be included in the iteration, like `path`, `url`, etc and your front matter, e.g. for `_my_collection/something.md`:

```
next:

path: _my_collection/something.md

output: <p></p>

url: /my_collection/something.html

id: /my_collection/something

content: <p></p>

collection: my_collection

relative_path: _my_collection/something.md

excerpt: <p></p>

previous:

draft: false

categories:

slug: something

ext: .md

tags:

date: 2017-05-23 14:43:57 -0300
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. I was expecting it to return the key-value pairs but I guess it just returns the key.

Comment: I've been looking for this loop. Thanks a lot.